# If I iterate over a collection that is actually a list in java, will the collection have order?

Tags: java, list, loops, inheritance, collections

```
List<String> stringList;

//fill with strings somehow

Collection<String> stringCollection = (Collection<String>) stringList;

for(String str : stringCollection){
  //will this loop be guaranteed to iterate in the order found in stringList
}
```

I think it is guaranteed that this for-each loop will iterate in the correct order, since the [syntactic sugar actually uses an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work?rq=1) and the [`iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator()) method is overridden in `List` to have an order. Since the run time type of `stringCollection` is a `List`, then it will use the overridden method which starts at the beginning of the list. Is this correct?

Comment: did you try it out? not that difficult to write a test case for it.. if you did try, what happened? ;)

Comment: @posdef trying it out will not answer the question if this behavior is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the enhanced for loop will use the iterator of the provided collection. So if b is really a list (runtime type), then the order will be guaranteed.

Note that with the new stream API (Java SE 8) this is a little bit different.

While b.stream() would still guarantee the order, b.parallelStream() wouldn't.

Also see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#ordering

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator()

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this collection. There are no
>   guarantees concerning the order in which the elements are returned
>   (**unless this collection is an instance of some class that provides a
>   guarantee**).

Answer (score 1):

## Yes.

`Collection.iterator` is implemented by the JDK implementations of `Collection`, like `ArrayList`. This is inherent to how object oriented programming works; if you call a method of an object where you only know one of it's interfaces, it will still call the method of the fully implemented class.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the `Collection` nor `List` interface provide an implementation for the `iterate()` method, so this implementation must come from the run-time type of the object you're iterating over. So yes, the collection will iterate in a predictable order if you use an ordered list.

Comment: It would come from the run-time type of the object even if one of Collection and List were abstract classes and did provide an implementation for the `iterator()` method.

Comment: @durron597 So? They're not abstract classes, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, but the implementation always comes from the run-time type. You said "implementation comes from the run-time type **because** the interfaces don't provide an implementation", but actually implementation comes from the run-time type **no matter what**.

Comment: @durron597 And in this case they are interfaces, so there's nowhere else for the implementation to even come from, which was my point. Don't use quotes when you're paraphrasing.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Since Java SE 8, interface can specify default implementations, but neither Collection nor List nor Iterable does in the case of the iterator-method.